# Get the contents of a specific attribute in span tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, scrapy

I have the following html:

```html
<span class="price" itemprop="price" content="2349.00">
                2&nbsp;349&nbsp;KČ            </span>
```

I need to get the contents of the content attribute ("2349.00"), is this possible with scrapy?

I have tried the following:

```py
response.css('span.content').get()
```

but obviously it didn't work.... is it possible to reference to other attributes similat as the class name and get their contents??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
response.css('span::attr(content)').get()
```